# Python for loop causes system crash

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, bigdata

I need to find all lines of a text file containing a particular string and write each line in a different text file. How can I improve my code to prevent system crash for reading first 5,000,000,000 lines of a big text file (6GB size)? After compiling the code my pc running slow, and suddenly freezing up. Even I stop compiling process, memory remains occupied and same problem comes up. My IDE is Spyder and I use Python 2.7. 
Thank you!

My code is:

```
import fileinput

ot = 'N'
j = 1
i = 1
string = "ABCD"

for line in fileinput.input(['/../myfile.txt']):
    if i<=5000000000:
        if string in line:
            output = open(ot + str(j) + '.txt', 'w')
            output.write(line)
            output.close()
            j += 1
        i += 1
```

Comment: Try using `context manager`: `with line in open('file.txt', 'r'):`

Comment: If you try read a 50MB file, what's the result?

Comment: @Chien-Wei Huang, the code works maximum for i = 1,000,000 and with smaller text files for instance 250MB but for more than them my system shows not enough memory (My OS is UBUNTU 13.10 and my pc's memory is 8GB).

Comment: If you remove the three lines from `output = open(ot + str(j) + '.txt', 'w')` to `output.close()`, what will happen?

Comment: I test with 2GB file without writing file in Mac environment, this works. Don't know the problem is related to file number limits in one directory or may related to the OS environment. My program memory only costs 1X MB.

Comment: I think you need to get rid of the temporary variables (`i`,`j`,) and replace them with meaningful variable names so we can figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using file input to open one file, although I don't see why it should make a difference functionally. If you are only opening one file, you should just use `open`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
file_input = open('mhyfile.txt','r')
for line in file_input:
    #Your code here
```

The `for line in file_input:` loop will read the file line by line. But I test in my linux system and find fileinput.input() use no more memory. I think you should give more information about your problem.

One possible problem is that you write too many files into your disk and cause the system crash. You can try to write the selected lines into one single file and mark the line number `j`.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import izip
ot = 'N%d.txt'
j = 1
lim = 5*10**9
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    #the xrange part replaces the i < 5e9 thing you had.
    for line, _ in izip(f,xrange(lim)):
        if 'ABCD' in line:
            output = open(ot % j, 'w')
            output.write(line)
            output.close()
            j += 1
```

This should run fine, but it might take a while if your  file is huge, though it shouldn't take up much memory.

**EDIT**
 
I added izip to avoid eating up tons of memory. izip is like zip, except it returns a generator instead of list.

Comment: @Emely_sh Actually, I think this might make everything load in memory? lol. If it does, I have no idea why it worked when the others wouldn't. In python3 zip would return a zip object, which would then lazily give each item as it is iterated through. But in python 2 this just forces the first, at most 5 billion, lines into a list of tuples, I think. which should eat up a ton of memory if the file is large enough.

Comment: my pc didn't crash using zip but it was so slower than izip; izip just used 14% of memory :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to choose just the first *limit* items of an iterator is to use `islice` from 
itertools - `islice(my_file, limit)` is similar to `my_file.readlines()[:limit]`, except that it avoids reading the whole file into memory. Counting just the lines with a given string in them is only a little bit more complex: use a generator expression to get just those lines, then islice *those*.

```
from itertools import islice
ot = 'N%d.txt'
limit = 5000000000  

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
   lines = (line for line in f if 'ABCD' in line)
   for j, line in enumerate(islice(lines, limit), start=1):
       with open(it % j, 'w') as out:
          out.write(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
file_num = 1

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i in range(5000000000):
        if file.readline(i) == 'ABCD':
            with open('N' + file_num + '.txt', 'w') as write_file:
                write_file.write(file.readline(i))
                file_num += 1
```

Not sure how well it well help with crashing but it is much cleaner.  Ask questions below.

Comment: I got this error "for i in range(5000000000): MemoryError"

Comment: @Emely_sh try `xrange` instead

Comment: Hi, just a suggestion, don't use the "file" keyword as your file handler. Also, you can just iterate over the file without calling "file.readline(i)". And file.readline(i) == 'ABCD' is wrong. The op is checking for the line containing 'ABCD', not that the line is 'ABCD'. Also default mode for opening file is read, so the flag 'r' is redundant.

Comment: @Broseph I didn't get memory problem using xrange but Spyder closed unexpectedly and the problem is still there.

Comment: @Emely_sh try something like locoyou's answer below.